# Android Camera Privacy Policy

Tags: android, android-camera, privacy-policy

I received an email from Google

Policy issue: Google Play requires developers to provide a valid privacy policy when the app requests or handles sensitive user or device information. Your app requests sensitive permissions (e.g. **camera**, microphone, accounts, contacts, or phone) or user data, but does not include a valid privacy policy. **Please resolve this issue by January 30, 2017, or administrative action will be taken to limit the visibility of your app, up to and including removal from the Play Store.** Thanks for helping us provide a clear and transparent experience for Google Play users.

I've searched for a privacy policy that contains camera section but i had no result from stackoverflow or from google. I also downloaded 9 apps but not a single app in Google Play that uses **camera**  has privacy policy. I started to think that they made this up to torment me:) What should i write to camera section inside the privacy policy, i would be grateful if anyone possess privacy policy can share.

I tried iubenda and some other sites too. This is my last resort not a quick answer request. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Talk to your attorney. Only your attorney can help you craft a policy that matches your app, Google's terms, and the laws in your area. This is one of the reasons why [questions about app store policies are off-topic for Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/272165/are-developer-centric-questions-about-application-stores-on-topic).

Comment: I don't have an attorney. I need a privacy policy with camera section in it. It's sufficient that it's a general camera section since i don't use any user info in any forms.

Comment: If anyone needs an answer to my question, i found the answer and explained it [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/42141408/how-i-can-add-privacy-policy-to-my-app-not-only-on-store-listing/42165664#42165664)

Comment: @Thracian Did you craft your own privacy policy? Do you have your own site?

Comment: https://app-privacy-policy-generator.firebaseapp.com