# Android request permission doesn't work

Tags: android, android-permissions

My problem is the request permission window doesn't show up for the permissions below. But if I changed the permissions to request from

```
static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
    Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
    Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
};
```

to

```
static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
    Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE
};
```

it works and I don't know why. So the dialog shows up for `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE`, but not for `PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS` and `CALL_PHONE`. Is my code wrong?
Manifest:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.administrator.myapplication">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CALL_PHONE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
             <intent-filter>
                 <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                 <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
             </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

Activity:

```
import android.Manifest;
import android.os.Build;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.annotation.RequiresApi;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.List;

import static android.content.pm.PackageManager.PERMISSION_DENIED;
import static android.support.v4.content.PermissionChecker.PERMISSION_GRANTED;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    protected static final int PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE = 11186;
    static final String[] PERMISSIONS = new String[]{
        Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS,
        Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE
    };
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        checkPermission(PERMISSIONS);
    }
    protected void checkPermission(String... permissions) {
        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            String[] requestPermissions = getRequestPermissions(permissions);
            if (requestPermissions.length > 0)
                requestPermissions(requestPermissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);
        } else {
            int[] grantResults = new int[permissions.length];
            Arrays.fill(grantResults, PERMISSION_GRANTED);
            onRequestPermissionsResult(PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE, permissions, grantResults);
        }
    }


    @RequiresApi(api = Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
    private String[] getRequestPermissions(String[] permissions) {
        List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
        for (String permission : permissions) {
            if (checkSelfPermission(permission) == PERMISSION_DENIED) {
                list.add(permission);
            }
        }
        return list.toArray(new String[list.size()]);
    }
}
```

> build.gradle:

```
  android {
    compileSdkVersion 25
    buildToolsVersion "25.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.administrator.myapplication"
        minSdkVersion 17
        targetSdkVersion 25
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    productFlavors {
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(include: ['*.jar'], dir: 'libs')
    androidTestCompile('com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:2.2.2', {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'support-annotations'
    })
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
    testCompile 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Please check your minSdk version in your build.gradle file, and make sure your APK is deploying in SDK(mobile) version above 22 (M).

Comment: minSdkVersion 17
targetSdkVersion 25 is that wrong?

Comment: Its not wrong , check your mobile version is M or higher , and if u want to test it manually goto settings-> apps->select your application-> u will get the  options to turn off permission manually. then u can check it. hope it will helps. else dubug your activity

Comment: my mobile  is android 7.0.and I check setting too.My app don't have the call_photo permission ,but it don't show the request whidow pops ,when i debug ,code can run to "requestPermissions(requestPermissions, PERMISSION_REQUEST_CODE);" this line,but nothing show TnT

Comment: but I run in android7.0device

Answer (score 0):

It has nothing to do with min sdk. Target Sdk must be 23 or higher to ask permissions and also runtime permission dialog is available for devices with 23 or above. If you try your code on a device with lower than 23 you won't be able to see permissions dialog, it will be like those permissions are accepted on the background.

Another issue is permissions is there are 2 types of permissions:

Normal permissions, and dangerous permission.

Only dangerous permissons can be asked on runtime. But it should work for Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE since they are in dangerous permissions group. [You can check dangerous and normal permissions.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7339743/android-permissions-how-can-i-learn-which-are-dangerous-vs-normal)

Comment: thanks,but the problem cant still be solved ,why Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE work ,    Manifest.permission.PROCESS_OUTGOING_CALLS, Manifest.permission.CALL_PHONE dont work,the are also belong to dangerous

Comment: I actually never tried those 2 permissions but i think issue can be about the code. There could be something wrong with asking multiple permissions. Can you check it with another permissions such as location or camera?

Comment: I have tried some.dont work:SEND_SMS,location,GET_ACCOUNTS     work :camera,READ_CALENDAR

Comment: Use [this utility class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42143285/checking-if-permissions-have-been-granted-already-by-user-in-android/42143563#42143563) to ask permissions one by one, or multiple permissions at once. Modify location, camera, etc. to your needs and it will be fine and your MainActivity will be cleaner.

Comment: I think your issue is `ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(activity,
     listPermissionsNeeded.toArray(new String[listPermissionsNeeded.size()]),
     REQUEST_PERMISSION_MULTIPLE)`

Comment: I try it too TnT~~~could you please try to run the code on your free time ,please~~

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem. Maybe someone will be useful. You need to add to the Manifest:

```
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.telephony" android:required="false"/>
```